# Nilpotent Operator and Invariant Subspace

Tags: vector-spaces, nilpotence, invariant-subspace

Let T : V → V be a linear transformation and suppose that for some v ∈ V ,
$T^k(v) = 0$ but $T^{k−1}(v) \neq 0$. 
Prove that the set $B = ${${T^{k−1}(v), . . . , T(v), v}$}
is linearly independent, and its span U is T-invariant. Find the matrix of
T restricted to U relative to the basis B.

I figured out set B is linearly independent.

Suppose
$$av+a_1T(v)+a_2T^2(v)+...+a_{k-1}T^{k-1}(v)=0$$
If it is not linearly independent, $a_0=a_1=a_2=...=0$

and using $T^k(v)$=0 to get $T(v)=bT(v)+b_1T^2(v)...+b_{k-2}T^{k-1}(v)$ $\in$w

But how to find the matrix of T restricted to U and what does relative to the basis B mean?

Comment: If it is not independent, then all coefficients are zero?

Comment: @SahibaArora I think so

Comment: A set $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots, v_n\}$ is said to be linearly independent if $a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n =0 $ implies $a_1=a_2=\cdots = a_n =0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$a_0v+a_1T(v)+\cdots+a_{k-1} T^{k-1}(v) =0\hspace{1cm}(1)$$
Then $$a_0T(v)+a_1T^2(v)+\cdots+a_{k-2} T^{k-1}(v) =0$$
which implies $$a_0T^2(v)+a_1T^3(v)+\cdots+a_{k-3} T^{k-1}(v) =0$$
Proceeding this way in $k$ steps, we get $$a_0T^{k-1}(v)=0$$
This shows $a_0=0$.

Substituting this in $(1)$, we get $$a_1T(v)+\cdots+a_{k-1} T^{k-1}(v) =0$$

Repeating the argument as before, we get $$a_0=a_1=\cdots=a_{k-1}=0$$

This proves B is linearly independent.

Let $U=\rm{span}\  B$ and $w \in U$. Then there exists scalars $b_0,b_1,\cdots,b_{k-1}$ such that
$$w=b_0v+b_1T(v)+\cdots+b_{k-1}T^{k-1}(v)$$
Therefore,$$T(w)=b_0T(v)+b_1T^2(v)+\cdots+b_{k-2}T^{k-1}(v)$$
Thus, $T(w) \in U$. This shows that $U$ is $T-$invariant.

I'll let you find the matrix yourself now.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am just confused about how to find the matrix since I don't know what does restricted to U mean.

Comment: @Castalia520, It means that you restrict the domain of $T$ to the subspace $U$.

Comment: how should I approach it? Can you give me some hints?

Comment: Use the general approach to find the matrix using your basis as $B$.